# Shapeless. Refer to all case classes of 1 constructor argument

Tags: json, scala, shapeless, case-class

I am trying to generalize over all case classes of 1 argument constructor to create Json serializers for them using shapeless.

What I have done so far is:

```
object ShapelessJsonOFormat extends ProductTypeClassCompanion[OFormat] {
  object typeClass extends ProductTypeClass[OFormat] {
    override def product[H, T <: HList](ch: OFormat[H], ct: OFormat[T]): OFormat[H :: T] = new OFormat[H :: T] {
      override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[H :: T] =
        for {
          h <- ch.reads(json)
          t <- ct.reads(json)
        } yield h :: t


      override def writes(o: H :: T): JsObject = ch.writes(o.head) ++ ct.writes(o.tail)
    }

    override def emptyProduct: OFormat[HNil] = new OFormat[HNil] {

      override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[HNil] = JsSuccess(HNil)

      override def writes(o: HNil): JsObject = JsObject.empty
    }

    override def project[F, G](
      instance: => OFormat[G],
      to: (F) => G,
      from: (G) => F): OFormat[F] = new OFormat [F] {
      override def writes(o: F): JsObject = instance.writes(to(o))

      override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[F] = instance.reads(json).map(from)
    }
  }
}
```

I have not tried it but it is not really what I want. The problem is that extending ProductTypeClassCompanion implies generalizing over all HLists so to be able to "add" two jsons I am forced here to play with JsonObjects (see the `++` in `override def writes(o: H :: T): JsObject = ch.writes(o.head) ++ ct.writes(o.tail)`). What I really need is to generalize over all HList of type `T :: HNil`. Is this possible? Otherwise I am enforced to make all my case classes extend `Product1[T]`.

Comment: Completely unrelated to the meat of your question, but I believe you can say `override object typeClass`, which is cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to restrict this to only working on single argument case-classes, then you cannot use `ProductTypeClass`. The purpose of it is to generalize inductively to *all* products of arbitrary arity. You want to stick to arity 1, so you have a conflict. You just have to write everything yourself without the (small) boilerplate `ProductTypeclass` abstracts for you.

```
object ShapelessJsonOFormat {
  implicit def caseHListArity1[Head](implicit
    headFmt: Lazy[OFormat[Head]] // Use Lazy in some places to get around the (incorrect) implicit divergence check in the compiler
  ): OFormat[Head :: HNil] = new OFormat[Head :: HNil] {
    // ... serialize a Head :: HNil given headFmt.value: OFormat[Head]
  }

  implicit def caseGeneric[I, O](implicit
    gen: Generic.Aux[I, O],
    oFmt: Lazy[OFormat[O]]
  ): OFormat[I] = new OFormat[I] {
    // ... serialize an I given a Generic I => O and oFmt.value: OFormat[O]
  }
}
```

From the looks of it, your major complaint is that you need to hack together multiple `JSONObject`s in the arity-abstracted version. This is because you are using `Generic`, not `LabelledGeneric`, and so you don't have the ability to give field names to the elements of the product, so they get mushed together on one level. You can normally use `LabelledProductTypeClass` for that, but it doesn't *quite* work here, so we're stuck with our own boilerplate. This version works on any arity.

```
type OFormatObject[A] = OFormat[A] { def write(value: A): JsObject }
object ShapelessJsonOFormat {
  implicit val caseHNil: OFormatObject[HNil] = new OFormat[HNil] {
    override def read(json: JsValue) = HNil
    override def write(value: HNil) = JsObject.empty
  }

  implicit def caseHCons[
    HeadName <: Symbol,
    Head,
    Tail <: HList
  ](implicit
    headFmt: Lazy[OFormat[Head]],
    nameWitness: Witness.Aux[HeadName],
    tailFmt: Lazy[OFormatObject[Tail]]
  ): OFormatObject[FieldType[HeadName, Head] :: Tail]
  = new OFormat[FieldType[HeadName, Head] :: Tail] {
    private val fieldName = nameWitness.value.name // Witness[_ <: Symbol] => Symbol => String
    override def read(json: JsValue): FieldType[HeadName, Head] :: Tail = {
      val headObj = json.asJsObject.get(fieldName)
      val head = headFmt.read(headObj)
      val tail = tailFmt.read(json)
      field[HeadName](head) :: tail
    }
    override def write(value: FieldType[HeadName, Head] :: Tail): JsObject = {
      val tail = tailFmt.write(value.tail)
      val head = headFmt.write(value.head)
      tail + JsObject(fieldName -> head) // or similar
    }
  }

  implicit def caseLabelledGeneric[I, O](implicit
    gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[I, O],
    oFmt: Lazy[OFormatObject[O]]
  ): OFormatObject[I] = new OFormat[I] {
    override def read(json: JsValue): I = gen.from(oFmt.value.read(json))
    override def write(value: I): JsObject = oFmt.value.write(gen.to(value))
  }
}
```

The idea here is to use the refinement `OFormatObject` to talk about `OFormat`s that are guaranteed to `write` `JsObject`s. There is an `OFormatObject[HNil]` that's just `{ read = _ => HNil; write = _ => {} }`. If there's a serializer for `Head` (`OFormat[Head]`), an object serializer for `Tail` (`OFormatObject[Tail]`), and we have some singleton type that represents the field name of `Head` (type parameter `HeadName <: Symbol`, realized in `Witness.Aux[HeadName]`), then `caseHCons` will produce a `OFormatObject[FieldName[HeadName, Head] :: Tail]`, which looks like `{ read = { headName: head, ..tail } => head :: tail; write = head :: tail => { headName: head, ..tail }`. We then use `caseLabelledGeneric` to bring the solution for `HList`s-with-`FieldType`s into general case classes.

Comment: When I said that I was forced to use JsObject I meant that what I really want is to use Format (JsValue). Never mind. In the first portion of code, does the caseGeneric function have to exist? Also, how is a single argument case class converted to T :: HNil ? I read that you need Generic.Aux right? And finally, I suppose that I will need to write (well, they are already written) Formats for String, Int, ... and every type T, right? 
And thanks for the other portion of code with LabelledGeneric, I find it very usefull to understand shapeless.

Comment: `caseGeneric` is what makes the solution on `HList` work on case classes. `caseHListArity1` makes an implicit format only for `T :: HNil`. `caseGeneric` then says that if there's `gen: Generic[I]` that translates `I` to/from `O`, and there's a `Format[O]`, it will translate the `Format[O]` with the `Generic.Aux[I, O]` into a `Format[I]`. That's what `Generic` is about: forgetting the specific information in case classes to produce easy-to-abstract-with `HList`s, so problems are first solved on `HList`, and then translated by `Generic` to work on case classes.

Comment: OMG. I've just tried it. I still have some trouble understanding Generic but it is clearer now... Well, your solution works perfectly, even with nested case classes. Thank you!